# i wanna calculate the umask in linux

Tags: linux, umask

what value of mask should i use to have -rwxr-xr-- for files and dr-xrwxrw- for files at the same time.
I tried 201 for the directories and 022 for the files
but is there any unmask that works for both of them at the same time.
what should I use I don't know which one to use so can someone help me.

Comment: You really want newly created files to be executable?

Answer (score 0):

> but is there any unmask that works for both of them at the same time.

Well, no, because you want different outcomes for files and directories so you can't do that with 1 umask value.